Woocommerce: "Edit Page" changes not displayed on Shop page
I set up my Woocommerce shop with no problems. On the page that is designated as the "shop" front page (the page you see when you arrive in the shop, it is titled "Welcome") I made some edits: I added a few images, a "featured products" block, and a custom block of images leading to the different shop categories.
On launch day, 2 weeks ago, everything looked fine. Then there was a woocommerce database update (1-2 days ago) and now, for some reason, the front page only displays an "Archive" page listing all products in the shop. My banners and images I added are not shown - it's as if the page uses a different template or something and overwrites my edits.
The weird thing is: when I edit this page ("Welcome"), I can see my images etc. in the editor. If I designate another page as the front page and access the "Welcome" page separately, it shows correctly. Only when I designate it the front page does it completely display the wrong way.
Does anyone have an idea why this might happen?

As a third party plugin Woocommerce is off-topic for this Stack. Your best avenue would be the plugin's own support forum.

I figured it out: I am using the Twenty Twenty Five theme, which isn't Woocommerce compatible. I now set the Welcome Page as my Front Page, but simply didn't designate it as my Shop page. I added all the woocommerce content on there manually anyway, so I realised I don't need to declare it as a shop page to generate anything. It works now, just as a regular page. :)
